# Quadratic curve uniquely determined by five points in the plane via linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, quadratic-forms

Define a quadratic curve by $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \; | \; Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F = 0\}$. I want to show that given $5$ points in the plane there exists a quadratic curve that passes through each of them. The goal is to use only linear algebra and I want to be sure this approach doesn't miss anything.

Assume we have a collection of five points in the plane say $\{(x_i,y_i)\}_{1 \leq i \leq 5}$. Let $$V = \{Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F \; | \; A,...,F \in \mathbb{R} \}$$ so it's set of all polynomials which define quadratic curves. If we give this set the same pointwise operations that we do for $\mathbb{F}[x]$ we have a vector space, and moreover $\dim(V) = 6$. The reason it has 6 dimensions is because it's basically just $\mathbb{F}[x] \cup \mathbb{F}[y]$ but we don't count the constant term twice and we have to add the mixed $xy$ term.

So next define a map $T:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^5$ by $f \mapsto (f(x_1,y_1),f(x_2,y_2),...,f(x_5,y_5))$. We can check this transformation is linear because for $f,g \in V$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that
$$
T(f+\alpha g) = ((f+\alpha g)(x_i,y_i)) = (f(x_i,y_i)+\alpha g(x_i,y_i)) = T(f)+\alpha T(g)
$$
Then by the rank-nullity theorem we know that $\dim(\ker(T)) \geq \dim(V) - \dim(W)$ and so here $\dim(\ker(T)) \geq 6-5 = 1$. This means that there exists some non-zero quadratic curve $f \in V$ such that $f(x_i,y_i) = 0$ for $1\leq i \leq 5$. Hence we have a quadratic curve that passes through whatever the five points were, and moreover because this is a subspace of $V$ it's technically a family of quadratic curves because we can scale them.

Are there any mistakes in the proof idea? Are there any possible cases I've neglected? How might I refine the proof to make it more concise? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What is $W$? The title refers to a curve *uniquely* determined (up to re-scaling presumably) by 5 points in the plane. But you've only attempted to prove $\dim \ker T \geq 1$ which means the subspace could e.g. have dim 2 in which case no uniqueness claim can be made. If you just want the existence of *some* non-zero curve, consider the maximal rank of $\begin{bmatrix} x_1^2 & x_1y_1 & y_1^2 & x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\ x_2^2 & x_2y_2 & y_2^2 & x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\ x_3^2 & x_3y_3 & y_3^2 & x_3 & y_3 & 1 \\ x_4^2 & x_4y_4 & y_4^2 & x_4 & y_4 & 1 \\ x_5^2 & x_5y_5 & y_5^2 & x_5 & y_5 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Comment: Sorry $W = \mathbb{R}^5$ here. Ok so this only shows the existence of some curve, but it doesn't show it's unique? @user8675309 But because we can always scale the polynomial and fit the same points should I have written a unique *family* of quadratic curves?

Comment: What is your goal? Are you trying to show the curve is unique up to re-scaling -- i.e. do you want to show (i) $\dim \ker T=1$? Or are you satisfied with the much weaker claim of (ii) $\dim \ker T\geq 1$?  It seems you attempted (ii) though I think your title indicates (i). A red flag for (i) is you never stated (/used) the 5 points being in general position which is vital.  In any case (i) takes a lot of work though I gave a linear algebra based proof here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3542374/matrix-of-constraints-shows-that-a-conic-is-determined-uniquely/3545054#3545054

Comment: @user8675309 I want to show that given any five points in the plane, there exists some quadratic curve which passes through all of them. I may have wrongly assumed that I could express the issue that way, but I guess just want to confirm that I have shown the existence of such a quadratic curve.