Invertibility of Multivariate Vandermonde Matrix
I would like to know if there is any complete characterization for when the following multivariate Vandermonde matrix is invertible.
$$M = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & a_5 & a_6 \\
a_1^2 & a_2^2 & a_3^2 & a_4^2 & a_5^2 & a_6^2 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 & b_5 & b_6 \\
a_1b_1 & a_2b_1 & a_3b_3 & a_4b_4 & a_5b_5 & a_6b_6 \\
b_1^2 & b_2^2 & b_3^2 & b_4^2 & b_5^2 & b_6^2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Its not difficult to find values $a = (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6)$ and $b = (b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5,b_6)$ such that $M$ is invertible. For example let $a = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6)$ and $b = (x_1^3,x_2^3, x_3^3, x_4^3, x_5^3,x_6^3)$ such that $x_i\ne x_j$ for $i\ne j$ and $x_i > 0$. Then, $M$ simplifies to the $\textit{generalized}$  Vandermonde matrix
$$
\widetilde{M} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 \\
x_1^2 & x_2^2 & x_3^2 & x_4^2 & x_5^2 & x_6^2 \\
x_1^3 & x_2^3 & x_3^3 & x_4^3 & x_5^3 & x_6^3 \\
x_1^4 & x_2^4 & x_3^4 & x_4^4 & x_5^4 & x_6^4 \\
x_1^6 & x_2^6 & x_3^6 & x_4^6 & x_5^6 & x_6^6 \\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
whose determinant is
$$
\det(\widetilde{M}) = -(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6)\prod_{i<j}(x_i-x_j)
$$
(The negative sign may be incorrect, but its irrelevant.) Therefore, by the uniqueness and the positivity of $x_i$, $\widetilde{M}$ is invertible. However, this is not nearly a complete characterization. Additionally, I know that $(a_i,b_i) \ne (a_j, b_j)$ for $i\ne j$ in order for $M$ to have a chance of being invertible. Any papers/books covering this topic would be appreciated.
This question has been asked before (~5 years ago): How to chose vectors such that this Vandermonde-like matrix non-singular?, however, the responses were less than helpful.

I think this has little to do with Vandermonde matrices and a lot to do with conics.  E.g. if you delete the final column you recover this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3542374/matrix-of-constraints-shows-that-a-conic-is-determined-uniquely/ .   If instead you work over $\mathbb R[x,y]$ and replace $a_6$ with $x$ and $b_6$ with $y$, you can take the determinant and interpret that (at most) quadratic having a zero set precisely being a conic.
